# Solution explorer does not reflect actual source control status

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, and TFS 2010 server, my solution explorer does not display accurate status.

When I checkin my changes, old source control status  are still shown in the solution explorer:

[image]

Any clue?